# Allow only specific tokens in NSTokenField

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, token, nstokenfield

I'm currently implementing a NSTokenField and at the moment any text that the user enters will be transformed into a token.
I only want to allow a specific set of tokens, any other text shouldn't be transformed to a token.

Is there a way to check if an entered text is a valid token any only then transform it to a token leaving other text unchanged?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of comparing any token with an array of valid ones you define?  What's so difficult?

Comment: Sure, the concept is quite clear. The Tokens are automatically converted, I do not know how to prevent them from being "tokenised"

Comment: Which `NSTokenFieldDelegate` methods did you implement?

Comment: Thanks for that hint - it seems my shouldAdd delegate method was broken.